Cómo hacer que me muestre el número 10?
Tengo de tarea hacer un programa que muestre los números del 1 al 10 en inglés, pero solo muestra hasta el 9.
package unidad02.worksheet02b;


public class ContaEnIngles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      Escribe un programa en Java (ContaEnIngles) que recorra os números naturais do 1 ao 10 con un bucle for . 
//      Para cada número do bucle, mostrará por pantalla o nome do número en inglés usando un array para gardar os nomes dos números en inglés
        String[] numerosEnIngles = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };

        for (int i = 1; i < numerosEnIngles.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " - " + numerosEnIngles[i - 1]);
        }

    }

}


El i está iniciado en 1, cuando debería ser en 0. Esto es la posición, no el inicio.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Tienes la siguiente estructura:



indice
0
1
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10




valor
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten



Además, el largo de array es 11 (numerosEnIngles.length)
En tu for pones:
for (int i = 1; i < numerosEnIngles.length+1; i++)

Donde:

i comienza en 1
i debe ser menor que 11 (es decir, como máximo 10) y es donde tienes el problema

Además, tu estas restando 1 en numerosEnIngles[i - 1], entonces recorres desde 0 hasta 9, cuando lo necesario es recorrer desde 0 hasta 10
¿Como aumentar en 1 el recorrido del for?
Simplemente sumas 1:
                                          // ↓ sumo 1
for (int i = 1; i < numerosEnIngles.length + 1; i++) {

Otra alternativa es decir que sea <= (menor o igual) a numerosEnIngles.length
                // ↓ menor o igual
for (int i = 1; i <= numerosEnIngles.length; i++) {


En programación empezamos a contar desde el cero (salvo algunas excepciones como LUA), esto puede ser difícil de asimilar al principio, pero luego te acostumbras y se transforma en algo mecánico. La forma "tradicional" de recorrer un array es
for (int i = 0; i < numerosEnIngles.length; i++) 

Con i=0, no digo que sea la mejor forma, solo que es la más usada. Con el for anterior recorres cualquier array siempre y es fácil de recordar
String[] numerosEnIngles = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };
for (int i = 0; i < numerosEnIngles.length; i++) {
    System.out.println( (i+1) + " - " + numerosEnIngles[i]);
}


ya que la ibas a editar, podrias haber agregado el lenguaje ;)

Lo que podrías hacer es ponerle una variable que simplemente sea uno más cuando lo imprimes y dejarlo de esta manera, también ponerle un <= en vez de solo el <, lo que hace es decirle que si la variable i es menor o igual a 10 (la longitud del array) siga ejecutándose el bucle
int l = 0
for (int i = 0; i <= numerosEnIngles.length; i++) {
        l = i + 1
        System.out.println(l + " - " + numerosEnIngles[i]);
}

Editado con los comentarios, como algunos ejecicio que eh hecho siempre le cambiamos el valor inicial al declarar el for por esos lo deje como en el original.

También soluciona el problema, pero creo que es mejor práctica entender que i=0, es la posición inicial que está recorriendo el for. Incluso, en muchos programas, se autocompleta en 0.

De hecho estoy 100% de acuerdo con Excorpion. Lo correcto sería empezar el bucle en 0, y si quieres imprimir en consola los índices "humanos" (Empezando en 1 y no 0) imprimes i + 1. No usas i - 1 en código... la lógica cuanto más sencilla mejor, mucho más fácil de leer y mantener. Hay que aprender a separar la lógica de la representación de las cosas.
